# 'Error replacement has 100 rows, data has 0' following a simulation with a loop

Tags: r

I need to run 1999 simulations in which I create two ARMA(1,0) models, namely 
a(t)=a(t-1)+e(t) and b(t)=b(t-1)+v(t) so that I can run the regression model 
a(t)=c*b(t)+u(t) and store the coefficient c, its standard error and its t-statistic. I need to obtain 1999 t-statistics at the end.

```
num_reps <- 1999
num_obs <- 200
phi_1_1 <- 0.99
theta_1_1 <- 0
sigma_2 <- 1

arma_stats <- data.frame(time=1:num_obs, t_stat= numeric(num_obs))
time_series <- data.frame(time = 1:num_obs, arma_1_0y= numeric(num_obs), 
arma_1_0x = numeric(num_obs))


for (rep_num in 1:num_reps) {

  time_series[, 'arma_1_0y'] <- arima.sim(n = num_obs, list(ar = c(phi_1_1), 
  ma = c(theta_1_1)),sd = sqrt(sigma_2))

  time_series[, 'arma_1_0x']<- arima.sim(n = num_obs, list(ar = c(phi_1_1), 
  ma = c(theta_1_1)),sd = sqrt(sigma_2))

  fmla_string <- 'arma_1_0y ~ 0 + arma_1_0x'
  fmla <- as.formula(fmla_string)
  arma_1_0 <- lm(data = time_series, formula = fmla)


  coeff <- arma_1_0$coef
  std_err <- sqrt(diag(arma_1_0$var.coef))
  tstat <- coeff/std_err
  arma_stats[rep_num, 't_stat'] <- tstat


}
```

I obtain the following error:

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , "arma_1_0y", value = c(7.57073355990616,  : 
  replacement has 100 rows, data has 0

I am a beginner in R. What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: The line `arma_stats <- data.frame(id = character(0), t_stat= numeric(num_obs))` gives an error for me.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited this line. I hope this helps. I get a new error now: 'remplacement has length zero'. It seems like one of the problems is with 'data.frame'.

Comment: Note that `$var.coef` is NULL as that is not an element of the `list` output returned from the `lm` call. Not sure where you got that from?

Comment: I saw someone using this expression (most likely, in another setting) so I thought I could use it in this setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error derives in the standard error, *std_err*, assignment as it returns an empty matrix. In order to retrieve the parameter estimates from a `lm` call (i.e,. coeff, t-stats, std. err, p-value), consider using `coeff()` from a `summary(model)` object.

```
res <- summary(arma_1_0)  # FIRST ITERATION
coef(res)

#            Estimate Std. Error  t value     Pr(>|t|)
# arma_1_0x 0.5024706 0.05034849 9.979854 2.824744e-19
```

Also, since you do not dynamically build a formula, there is no need to convert a string formula as you can directly include the static formula object in `lm`. Hence, you can adjust accordingly:

```
for (rep_num in seq(num_reps)) {

  time_series[, 'arma_1_0y'] <- arima.sim(n = num_obs, list(ar = c(phi_1_1), 
                                                            ma = c(theta_1_1)),
                                                            sd = sqrt(sigma_2))

  time_series[, 'arma_1_0x'] <- arima.sim(n = num_obs, list(ar = c(phi_1_1), 
                                                           ma = c(theta_1_1)),
                                                           sd = sqrt(sigma_2))

  arma_1_0 <- lm(arma_1_0y ~ 0 + arma_1_0x, data = time_series)

  res <- summary(arma_1_0)      
  tstat <- coef(res)[, "t value"]
  arma_stats[rep_num, 't_stat'] <- tstat      

}
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know this! I 'accepted' Parfait's answer.